# Find a file which is 30 minutes old

Tags: find

How can I find the file which is of 30 minutes old in `/bin/ksh`?

Comment: Do you mean "had its contents changed 30 minutes ago" or "did not exist until it was created 30 minutes ago"? Also, what operating system are you using? Different operating systems come with different versions of `find`.

Comment: @ Mark Plotnick i want to find the file which were of 30 minutes old

Comment: I think he/she means *was created 30 minutes ago*. As if e.g. someone is X old, he/she was born X time ago.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With out `GNU/BSD find`

```
TZ=ZZZ0 touch -t "$(TZ=ZZZ0:30 date +%Y%m%d%H%M.%S)" /reference/file
```

and then `find . -newer /reference/file`

solution given by Stéphane Chazelas

Answer (score 28):

On Linux, there is no track of the creation time of a file. You can only access:

- the last modification time of the content (a creation counts as a modification of course), `mtime`,
- the last access time, `atime`,
- the last modification time of the meta-data, `ctime`.

If you want to look for files with a test based on these times, `find` (`man find`) can help you.

You would use it this way to find a file accessed exactly 30 minutes ago in your current directory and its subdirectories:

```
find -amin 30
```

Usually, you'll want to use an interval as it can be difficult to give an exact number of minutes:

```
find -amin +25 -amin -35
```

This will find files accessed more than 25 but less than 35 minutes ago.

And if you're interested only in modification time and not in access (i.e. read) time, replace `-amin` with `-mmin`.

Comment: you don't want atime. atime is access time.

Comment: @richard The OP didn't specify what he meant  so... Anyway I put `mtime` too in the answer

Comment: @ lgeorget when i use `-mtime 30` it was showing the files 30 days old.

Comment: @user2910201 Ups stupid me. `Xtime` options are for days and `Xmin` options for minutes. My bad, I edit the answer

Comment: @user2910201 but note that you can use `Xtime` with any reasonable time unit like `30m` for thirty minutes, or `5d` for five days

Comment: @igeorget, the question says 30 **minuets old**, things don't get reborn (not even younger) by looking at them.

Comment: @richard Ok, I understand your point, but my post _does_ answer that. It's only more general than it'd need to be. I edited it to clarify.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `mtime` to do so:

```
find . -mmin 30    #exactly 30 minutes old
```

Comment: this will tell you the files which was `created` or `modified` 30 minutes back

Comment: @ g4ur4v when i use `-mmin` it is showing `-mmin` is not a valid option

Comment: Try this out: `find /path -mtime +30m`

Comment: Not sure why it's not recognizing `-mmin`, I've looked up many examples using that command..